# How to include styles in angular.json with a glob pattern "**"

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript

Does anyone know how to include styles in angular.json like in scripts where you can use the glob pattern "**" like this:

```
{
   "input": "projects/",
   "glob": "**/assets/**/*",
   "ignore": [
       "**/styles.**"
    ],
    "output": "."
}
```

I tried this:

```
"styles": [
    "./projects/**/assets/styles.scss",
    "src/assets/styles/styles.scss"
],
```

Comment: Why? Since in scss the order of imports matters, I doubt it can be done. Can't you just create a new scss file, import the files individually and reference it from angular.json?